# How to query Group by and MAX(id) in the Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, express, group-by, sequelize.js, max

Hi There i want to ask how to produce data group by certain id and find max value of that id,

For example I have Table Student Quiz

```
id   student_id    score
1       2           200
2       2           100
3       3           300
4       3           200
```

I want the output like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    student_id: 2,
    score: 200
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    student_id: 3,
    score: 300
  }
]
```

How can i produce it using sequelize ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have created the proper sequlize model, Try using the following code snippet.

```
StudentQuiz.findAll({
    attributes: [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('score'))],
    group: ["student_id"],
    raw: true,
})
```